# Does knockout perform model binding asynchronously? if so, how do I prevent it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In the following code I am updating my knockout model property `SearchResults`, and then I am recomputing the size of all the columns in my html. I know the `_resizeColumns` function works correctly. However it is being run before the DOM has been updated with the search results. I have verified that `_resizeColumns` is being called by updating the background-color on all divs with yellow. The divs that existed prior to the model update are getting set to yellow, but the search results are not.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'foo.com',
    data: postData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: true,
    success: function(data) {
      model.SearchResults(data.d); // updates the DOM with the search results via knockout.js
      _resizeColumns();            // does not resize the columns because they haven't been added to the DOM yet
    },
    error: function() { alert('error'); }
});
```

The search results do get added to the DOM, it is just after my call to `_resizeColumns`

**Update**
I don't think knockout is running asynchronously. I believe it is the web browser itself updating the DOM asynchronously.

**Update 2**
The `_resizeColumns()` function works when called directly from `$(document).ready()`.

**Update 3**
I have two versions of `_resizeColumns()` one that uses jquery selectors to both get and set the widths, and another that stores into a 2d array when getting widths, and accesses that 2d array when setting them. The 2d array version performs faster. The 2d array version also causes the problem in my original question above. The jquery only version does not.

Comment: Your model.SearchResults() should stuff the data in and alert anything that is subscribed to it prior to continuing on and running _resizeColumns.  To see this in action put an alert(model.SearchResults); and you should see that your DOM has data when the alert pauses the script execution.

Comment: Have you considered making the columns resize based on a ko computed property?

Comment: @PWKad the issue is knockout's binding runs async, so you don't know when the DOM will be bound with the new data, and there's no way to forward a callback method to run when that happens, I tried subscribing to the observable, but that executes every time before the data is bound and not after, would love to hear how to know when the binding is done too.

Comment: @RoyiMindel Could you reference documentation supporting that the binding callbacks are performed asynchronously?  I have never seen a standard binding that is handled asynchronously, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @PWKad This issue shows you it does, and i have encountered the same issue a couple of times, you update an observable, right after that you do some work on the DOM element that is bound to it, your work will happen before the binding takes affect, that means its running async, if it would have been sync - the resizeColumns would happen after the data would have been rebound to the DOM element, but it doesn't - there lies the problem

Comment: Ok, this 'issue' is unproven anywhere, there are no fiddles showing the asynchronous nature of bindings that you are alluding to in this question, only the statement that 'it is happening async'.

Comment: @PWKad - given the asynchronous nature of this issue, getting it to recreate in a fiddle is nontrivial (I have tried already), and what may get it to recreate on my machine may not work on your machine. You are just going to have to take my word on it, that this occurs as described in the question.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, what happens on my browser is the same as yours, machine makes no difference.

Comment: Are you using any Knockout plugins?

Comment: @MichaelBest just mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, Knockout does not perform bindings asynchronously unless you force it to, explicitly.  By default it will notify all subscribers before moving on to your next statement.

http://jsfiddle.net/uVgdF/

This can be seen like this -

```
self.updateSomethings = function () {
    self.somethings.push(new something('William', 1234432));
    alert('binding complete');
}
```

Comment: Checked it out, my issue was the inability to catch updating observable after it changed the DOM element, subscribe fire before the DOM is rebound to the new values. - so not the same issue, i take it back

Comment: Glad you were able to locate your problem.  Good luck, enjoy knockout, you will love it

Answer (score 2):

In my application, I had a similar issue--that I needed to set the column widths after content was rendered by Knockout. My solution was to create a custom binding that I could place on the `<table>` element that would update whenever the table was updated (because it was bound to the same observable array). When trying to run the binding synchronously, I ran into trouble, but it was simple enough to have it run asynchronously. Here is my binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fixColumnWidths = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $headings = $(element).find('thead th');
                if (!$headings.length) {
                    $headings = $(element.rows[0].cells);
                }
                $headings.width('').width(function(index, width) {
                    return width;
                });
            });
        }
    }
};
```